# Binding data from XmlDataProvider to a ListBox fails in XAML in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, xmldataprovider

Recently I started to learn WPF. When learning about binding data, I create a `listbox` and binds data from a `XmlDataProvider` to it. Here's the code for `XmlDataProvider`:

```
<Grid.Resources>
......
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="ExpenseDataSource" XPath="Expenses">
    <x:XData>
        <Expenses xmlns="">
            <Person Name="Mike" Department="Legal">
                <Expense ExpenseType="Lunch" ExpenseAmount="50" />
                <Expense ExpenseType="Transportation" ExpenseAmount="50" />
            </Person>
            <Person Name="Lisa" Department="Marketing">
                <Expense ExpenseType="Document printing"
                         ExpenseAmount="50"/>
            <Expense ExpenseType="Gift" ExpenseAmount="125" />
            </Person>
            <Person Name="John" Department="Engineering">
                <Expense ExpenseType="Magazine subscription" 
                         ExpenseAmount="50"/>
                <Expense ExpenseType="New machine" ExpenseAmount="600" />
                <Expense ExpenseType="Software" ExpenseAmount="500" />
            </Person>
            <Person Name="Mary" Department="Finance">
                <Expense ExpenseType="Dinner" ExpenseAmount="100" />
            </Person>
        </Expenses>
    </x:XData>
</XmlDataProvider>
......
</Grid.Resources>
```

And here's code for the `Listbox`:

```
<Grid>
......
<ListBox Name="peopleListBox" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ExpenseDataSource}, XPath=Person}">
<!-- Name item template -->
    <DataTemplate>
        <Label Content="{Binding XPath=@Name}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox>
......
<Grid>
```

When I compile and run the code, the `ListBox` contains nothing. I try to find solutions from MSDN but cannot understand where the error is.

Comment: Okay, try setting the ItemsSource of the Listbox to be...
ItemsSource="{Binding Person}">
You also want to set your Grid's DataContext.as followed
<Grid DataContext={StaticResource ExpenseDataSource}>

Comment: @JesseGlover I tried <Grid DataContext={StaticResource ExpenseDataSource}> and there is an error in this sentence. And actually I do not want the DataContext of the Grid to be set to "ExpenseDataSource" because I have other Controls apart from the listBox and those Controls will be bound to other data in my C# code.

Comment: Found an error for you, unfortunately not home to fix it. Error is the set item source for the listbox is present during runtime from the static resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should at the very least get you started. I would suggest starting off a little simpler and work your way to the more difficult solutions.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <XmlDataProvider x:Key="ExpenseDataSource" XPath="Expenses">
                <x:XData>
                    <Expenses xmlns="">
                        <Person Name="Mike" Department="Legal">
                            <Expense ExpenseType="Lunch" ExpenseAmount="50" />
                            <Expense ExpenseType="Transportation" ExpenseAmount="50" />
                        </Person>
                        <Person Name="Lisa" Department="Marketing">
                            <Expense ExpenseType="Document printing"
                         ExpenseAmount="50"/>
                            <Expense ExpenseType="Gift" ExpenseAmount="125" />
                        </Person>
                        <Person Name="John" Department="Engineering">
                            <Expense ExpenseType="Magazine subscription" 
                         ExpenseAmount="50"/>
                            <Expense ExpenseType="New machine" ExpenseAmount="600" />
                            <Expense ExpenseType="Software" ExpenseAmount="500" />
                        </Person>
                        <Person Name="Mary" Department="Finance">
                            <Expense ExpenseType="Dinner" ExpenseAmount="100" />
                        </Person>
                    </Expenses>
                </x:XData>
            </XmlDataProvider>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <ListBox Name="peopleListBox" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" 
         DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ExpenseDataSource}}" ItemsSource="{Binding Name}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I trimmed your Listbox to not have the label with the datatemplate (you could actually substitute the data template for a stack panel within the Listbox.
I set the data context of your listbox to be the static resource and the itemssource to be Binding Name.
It will currently display the word Expenses as an individual string.

Comment: Thank you for solving this problem. I also use C# code to bind data instead of XAML and solve this problem.